# Installshield new version aside

Tags: .net, installshield

I am new at IntallShield LE and have a problem. I have two versions of the same .Net project (1.0.0.0 and 2.0.0.0). I need IntallShield to intall the second version aside the first one but it deletes version 1.0.0.0 and I have version 2.0.0.0 only in GAC folder.
How to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to SO:SEE. Please explain what is preventing you to have two installs, and what is your current imperfect solution, so that users may help you fix it. See [ask] if necessary.

Comment: Thanks! I have found out that the problem was in another thing )

Answer (score 0):

MSI (Technology behind Windows Installation) does not understand .NET assembly version. However it understands file version.

Two files with the same name cannot be present in the same folder. The only thing you can do is strong name those dlls and install them into the GAC.